# How to optimize count query on large table

Tags: php, mysql

I have table contains 300 Million record with two field "name" and "date". now
I need to count record of last month so I did

```
select count(*) from lenders_transaction WHERE dates >= now()-interval 1 month;
```

But it is taking long time , so I need advise How to optimize count query and how to get fast result.

Comment: Do you have an index on `dates` field?

Comment: check the EXPLAIN output to see what is going on

Comment: There is no index on dates field . If i add then it would make query fast ?

Comment: @valex . . . You should add that as an answer so others can upvote it.

Answer (score 4):

@Valex has the right solution, which is an index on the `date` field.

I want to comment that a table of 300 millions rows, and growing, is a large table.  This query suggests that recent data is more important than older data.  If so, you should be learning about partitioning.

Partitioning is a way of splitting a large table into smaller storage units.  If a query only needs to access one of them, then only that data is read for processing -- a big savings.  For instance, if your data were partitioned by month and you had 36 months of data, then your query would only have to access 2 months worth.  This would be a savings of almost 95% over reading all the data.

[Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/partitioning.html) is the MySQL documentation on partitioning.